# Scope of next() in Python

Tags: python, iterator

I am trying to use the `next` function on an iterator, however, I have a local variable in the same scope that is also named `next`.  The obvious solution is to rename the local variable, however, I'm fairly new to Python so I'm curious to learn how to prefix the `next` function so I achieve the desired behavior.

The code I'm using looks something like this:

```
for prev, curr, next in neighborhood(list):
    if (prev == desired_value):
        print(prev+" "+next)
        desired_value = next(value_iterator)
```

Note that I'm using Python 3.2.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `__builtins__.next` to refer to the `next` built-in function.

```
for prev, curr, next in neighborhood(list):
    if (prev == desired_value):
        print(prev+" "+next)
        desired_value = __builtins__.next(value_iterator)
```

However, as you point out, the obvious solution is to use a different name for your variable.

Answer (score 6):

You can call the `next()` method of the iterator directly. You lose, however, the ability to suppress `StopIteration` at the end of the iteration in favor of seeing a default value.

```
desired_value = value_iterator.next()
```

Note that in Python 3, this method has been renamed `__next__()`.

Answer (score 2):

Before you assign something to next, use something like:

```
real_next = next
```